# symfony 3 unable to set session variable

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am new to Symfony and it is giving me a tough time on setting sessions.

I am not sure what the session setup should be, so I am attempting to create a separate class to handle all session related functions.

I am aware that the $request object contains all the session information, but accessing it in a controller escapes me.

On the other hand I can access it and even change it on Twig, but that's not the proper way to handle this, I understand.

As it is, it throws an error

> Call to a member function set() on null

on the

> $session->set( 'cart_ads', 10 );

line on the SessionManagerController.php file. So it would seem it is not creating the $session variable which is set to null.

This is the setup:

On app_dev.php, ie, the front controller.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use AppBundle\Controller\SessionManagerController;


/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
SessionManagerController::sessionAction($request);//error here***
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

SessionManagerController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SessionManagerController extends Controller
{

    public function sessionAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->set( 'cart_ads', 10 ); //error here***

    } 
}
```

Comment: Your attempt to call sessionAction from app.php makes no sense.  You have access to the session when inside of a regular controller action. http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#managing-the-session

Comment: what do you mean with "I am aware that the $request object contains all the session information, but accessing it in a controller escapes me." ?

Comment: @Cerad, actually I am working with Symfony 3.2.8, so SessionInterface is not available. I did try though with injecting Request $request  but it throws an error saying that I did not provide an instance of $request. In the end it works as per Rendy Eko Prastiyo answer, but I would like to have done within the controller.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to apply your previous experiences with php sessions to the Symfony framework?  It is often best to try to learn the framework as it stands before trying to change the way it works.  I can see no use case for your session manager code and certainly no reason to call it from app.php.  If you are trying to execute code on each request then maybe take a look at kernel listeners.  I think after you implement a few more actions you might have a better idea of how sessions are used within Symfony.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session` you requested is not available in `$request` because you call `SessionManagerController::sessionAction($request);` before you call `$kernel->handle($request)`. Symfony attach `session` into `request` upon calling `$kernel->handle($request)`.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

// this method has to be called after you call $kernel->handle($request)
// so you will have session object attached to $request
SessionManagerController::sessionAction($request);

$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Any ideas why it would not work within the controller?

Comment: Because your `controller` is called before the `kernel` `handle` the application. The `handle` method is the heart of `Symfony`. If you want to learn more about the magic of `handle` method, you can learn it [here](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey/httpkernel-handle). If you want to modify your session outside the `main controller`, you can use [Kernel Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-events).